# How many objects can i retrieve from a parse class in android?

Tags: android, parse-platform

The following is a statement given in the [Parse Android Developers Guide](http://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#query-constraints):

> You can limit the number of results with setLimit. By default, results are limited to 100. In the old Parse hosted backend, the maximum limit was 1,000, but Parse Server removed that constraint

What does this statement actually mean? Does it mean that I can retrieve as many objects as I want from the parse class and display in ListView irrespective of the count of the objects?